# update statement does not make change

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have this class that connect to my database:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

/// <summary>
/// Summary description for Dcon
/// </summary>
public class Dcon
{
    public SqlConnection con;
    private SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    public SqlDataReader dr;

    public Dcon()
    {
        con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=E:\web\WebSite4\App_Data\Dbase.mdf;Integrated Security=True");
        con.Open();
        cmd.Connection = con;
    }

    public bool IUD(string sqls)
    {
        try
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = sqls;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            return true;
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public bool select(string sqls)
    {
        cmd.CommandText = sqls;
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if(dr.Read())
            return true;
        return false;
    }

}
```

and this code that make updtae to my database

```
if (s1.IUD("UPDATE users SET fname=N'" + TextBox1.Text + "',lname=N'" + TextBox2.Text + "',uname='" + TextBox3.Text + "',password='" + pass + "' WHERE (id=" + Request.QueryString["id"]+")"))
{
    Response.Redirect("success.aspx");
}
else
{
    Response.Redirect("faild.aspx");
}
```

its goes to success page but its not make change to my data, my code work at insert and select staments but i dont know why its not work when i use update statment, can any one help?!

Comment: Are you sure there's an actual match on your where clause?

Comment: Your sql is ripe for sql injection attack.

Comment: 1) What did `ExecuteNonQuery` return, and 2) **please** don't write any more code prone to [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Use [Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: A successful execution of IUD(..) only tells you that the method completed without exceptions. Doesn't tell you anything about the SQL that was executed.

Comment: This class can leak resources. If you have `IDisposable`-implemented classes as objects at your class level, your class should also implement `IDisposable` and `Dispose()` of those resources in its own `Dispose()` method. Also, you shouldn't have class-level variables be `public` - especially those which can be mutated. At the very least, make them `readonly` as well. Best practice, make them `private` and expose them via read-only properties if absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Multiple things to consider here. 
First and most important is use a `variable` and check what it returns to check the `# of rows` affected like this

```
int rows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

If it is `0` then there is surely something wrong with your query or there is no records with your selected criteria, Nothing else can happen except these two.

Note: Your code have several issues

- **Parameterized query** should be used to avoid **SQL Injections**
- **Dispose the object** after usage
- **QueryString** can be null, Check like this

  ```
  If(Request.QueryString["id"] != null)
  {
     // your update code here
  }
  ```